# google map not display in the middle of the frame

Tags: google-maps, jquery-mobile, google-maps-api-3

I create a Jquery mobile side with a embedding Google map, for some reasons, the map doesn't  display in the middle of the frame, and not allow move to the middle.
any help for where I can adjust it please:

http://johnd.smartagent.co.nz/users/92/properties/54634

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps API v3, jQuery UI Tabs, map not resizing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6455536/google-maps-api-v3-jquery-ui-tabs-map-not-resizing)

Comment: @geocodezip :How can I check please?

Answer (score 1):

Using this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/wptc/SWfRa/ to help test the problem in greater detail. Without changing the markup or code, the Align Center appears to work in Chrome; may try other browsers to narrow down the issues.

#### Map

```
    <div align="center" data-role="content">
        <div  id="map_canvas"></div>
    </div>



     </p>
```